# File names with version numbers...is it a good idea?

Tags: php, html, css, filenames

I have this custom-made CSS reset stylesheet that I keep updating and I always mention the date and version number inside so I can keep track of multiple copies.

Is it a good idea to name my stylesheets using veersion numbers? 
For example:

- **example_v1.0.css**
- **example_v1.0.1.css**

If it is, is it also a good idea for HTML, JS, and PHP files?

Answer (score 7):

It **IS** a good idea to maintain multiple versions.

However it is **not** a good idea to maintain multiple versions **manually**. 
There are tools to do that, called [source control/version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) tools, and these tools provide features over and above just maintaining versions.

Some of them include [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), [Git](http://git-scm.com), [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and [CVS](http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/).

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful reply. I'm going to try Git.

Answer (score 6):

No!.. Even for small projects use svn!

client: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/

server for Windows: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Comment: Mortis, SVN is not mandatory, any version control system will do.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea if you are extremely worried about caching. Never reusing a file name allows to:

1. Set expiration headers so the item never expires.
2. Make sure the browser is not displaying an obsolete version of the file.

It's not so good if it's only a way to replace a real source control tool.

Answer (score 3):

Use some kind of [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) (version control system) instead. It'll save you headache. There's a nice overview of few of them [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/18/the-top-7-open-source-version-control-systems/).

Comment: Thank you for the link! It helped put things into perspective but it seems they're all web based? Is there a more private tool for this?

Comment: They aren't web based. You can (in most of the cases) easily install them on localhost. Git or Mercurial would be the easiest to setup like this probably.

Answer (score 2):

Pfft. No. Use a [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) like everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a good idea in few situations:
1. You could easily have a preview of new version of a service and the old one for production.
2. You may may be forced to update half of a service or a front page only. It could be easier to have each versions in separate file than a set of hacks in one.

There are soft and hard links too on some filesystems too.

However, if You need a revision control, I would recommend a dedicated software for this purpose. I personally use Git (http://git-scm.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably most of your front end html or php files are going to be using the same style sheet/s so all you have to do is include a link to a version file which then references the actual css files.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include ("css-version.html") ?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your css-version file will be something like...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my.css?v=01" type="text/css" />
```

That way you only have to update the version number in css-version file and all the files which include the css-version will reload in browser.